# A line of pixels that is copying other colors from a certain area

Tags: laptop, display

I'm just asking if is there a problem with my laptop (Acer Nitro 5) screen because at the bottom for the screen a full line of pixel is copying a certain part of my screen which is the almost top part of the screen. It copied the colors exactly and its making me anxious if the screen is broken or something on the inside. I'm just scared because replacing the monitor is expensive because its a FHD 120Hz.

I'll send an image below so you guys can check if its a monitor problem or what.

[image: photo of the screen]

Comment: Does this happen also in safe mode? in UEFI? or in another OS? (e.g. some live Linux booted from USB). Any specific observations after changing the resolution? and/or refresh rate?

Comment: I can only concur. Try a fresh OS, e.g. an Ubuntu Live environment (bootable iso's are available on ubuntu.com). If the same happens, it's likely your hardware. If not, you have a driver issue and you should be able to resolve it by installing the recommended video driver, and if that doesn't help reinstall your OS.

Comment: I tried going in safe mode, UEFI, change resolution, and refresh rate. Its still there. Its highly likely a hardware problem which im kinda sad because I really need to replace the screen.